# How can I detect which driver a device is using?

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch, debian

I am using a Waveshare captivate touch LCD screen.  It uses the GT811 chipset for touch functionality.  The touch feature works perfectly when using Ubuntu 16.04LTS.  It doesn't work using Debian 8 with GNOME 3.14.1.

How can I detect what driver the GT811 is utilizing on my Ubuntu installation so I can install it in Debian?

These tests were done using the same computer (one harddrive for each OS)

Thanks,

Comment: You might have a different problem... I would assume the driver would be the same on debian and ubuntu(?). I doubt Canonical would want to change how the hardware detection is done. Why would they need to?

Comment: Yeah, you have a point. Any idea on what the problem could be?

Comment: Problems related to debian are off topic ;-)  I'd run through the generic commands (like "lspci" and "dmesg" to see if the device is seen on debian).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo lspci | grep 3D
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
```

I used a generic '3D" to find my graphics card. Note the 01:00 in front of the line and then do a ...

```
$ find /sys | grep drivers.*01:00
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nouveau/0000:01:00.0
```

So I am using the "nouveau" driver. When I change it to the 3rd party driver it will show ...

```
$ find /sys | grep drivers.*01:00
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvidia/0000:01:00.0
```

---

But you can also open "additional drivers" in the "software&updates" from dash. There most times are only 2 options: open source and 3rd party.

Comment: It is much easier to do it by `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`. Or run `lspci -k` and look through it.